# existence check and getting content for one-time URLs

Tags: php

I know that there are enough approaches to check the existence of a URL before throwing your usual `file_get_contents` but there is one problem. all of them try to request the file and I get nothing except the true or false out.

when dealing with URLs that can only be called one time (for example if they have an authorisation token that can only be used once to avoid repetition attacks) then I cant really check if the file exists and request again to get the actual output.

so essentially I need a way that calls the URL and if it returns that it is available in some kind then give me the output, but if not dont give me an error, but just return false.

Comment: Why can't you do file_get_contents, then just check if($contents !== false)?

Comment: yeah but file get contents throws an error, and that is something I dont want.

Comment: Put an @ in front of the file to suppress the E_WARNING, then check if it returns false.

Comment: isn't the @ usually REALLY BAD coding standards?

Comment: You aren't really overwhelmed with options. As far as standards go, in this case, you are explicitly handling the failure on the very next line, which is basically the purpose of the error suppression. If possible the HEAD preview would be reasonable as well, but this is a generally accepted option.

Comment: well I just read somewhere (I think also somewhere on stackexchange) that using an @ to supress the error is just really bad coding standards, similar to goto and exec, which should iirc not be used unless there is no other option.

Comment: "Unless there is no other option." Well that sort of answers it. Though, technically, you may have options with PHP 7 error handling.

Comment: well the point is that was I was asking whether or not there is another option.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you can do a HTTP HEAD request get a preview of the header.

Comment: but the question is how does the server handle it, not that it locks it down after the head request.

the greatest Idea would be if it would get the HTTP status code, if available, any output and NOT produce errors

Answer (score 0):

```
$fd = @ fopen('url', 'rb');
if ($fd) {
    fclose($fd);
    $contents = file_get_contents('url');
}
```

UPD:

You should write something like this (e.g. action of controller):

```
...
public function download()
{
    // chek auth and access rights
    // get and sanitize key
    // check existence of remote file
    // check key (try get available from DB)
    // get contents of existence file
    // set key (in DB) has used and/or generate new unique key for this file
}
...
```

Comment: ehm, doesnt that thing start a complete new request to the server when it exists.
the problem is that if once requested you WONT GET IT AGAIN.

Comment: @My1 $url = 'scheme://host[:port][/path][?secret_key=12345678]' when secret key has valid only once. But why you cant store access relations and/or this keys on DB?

Comment: the url works pretty much as you say but you code looks like it first tries to access it, if it gets something it closes the connection and calls again.
also the key would be valid only once to avoid repitition attacks

Comment: but wait, if you fopen it you essentially open the connection and get it ready for readng, so if we dont close the thing if we got something, but use the fopen'd ressource pointer it might work

Comment: @My1 but this is hidden URL for users. About this URL known only you application. And you can choose other protocols nfs, rsync, webdav, ftp, ssh or e.g. amazon clouds.